# ACTION_DOCK_EVENT subtypes

Tags: android, dock

I need to know when the device is connected or disconnected to a dock (car or desk). To do that I have a broadcast receiver and this line in the Manifest:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT"/>
```

And this is the receiver:

```
@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{  
   if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT")
   {  //This is a Dock event.
      //How can I know here if the event is connected or disconnected?
      //Can I also know if is it is a Car or a Desk dock?
   }
}
```

How can I know here if the event is connected or disconnected?
Can I also know if is it is a Car or a Desk dock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find both of those by looking at the intent's extras.  An explanation and example code is found here: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/docking-monitoring.html

Comment: Sorry, I already looked at it but I don't understand it. In the line: "int dockState = battery.getIntExtra(EXTRA_DOCK_STATE, -1);"  What is "battery"????

Comment: It's the incoming intent.  Probably a copy paste bug from the battery documents.